# PHP Library Create Microsoft Word document with Page Indexing

Tags: javascript, php, html, ms-word, prototype

I have a script which generates a report in Microsoft Word using thePHPWord library. I need a page index which will show the page numbers where each project in the report can be found.

I understand that PHPWord does not support page indexing, therefore the existing script which generates the word document, may need to be re-coded for a different library.
which library can I use for this?